# Shape in Illustrator so it can be editable in PowerPoint

Tags: adobe-illustrator, microsoft-powerpoint, osx

How to save a shape in Illustrator so it can be editable in PowerPoint 2016 (MAC OS). I should be able to recolour and it has to scalable on re-sizing.

Comment: On a Windows machine you can just copypaste and then ungroup and it will become native.

Comment: Can you help me out on MAC..??

Comment: Well, for starters, have you tried @joojaa's suggestion on your Mac?

Answer (score 2):

- Save your shape from Illustrator as .EMF file.
- Go to PowerPoint -> Insert a picture -> select your .emf file and
  click open.
- At this point it will act as a picture. You will have to
  right click the shape -> Group -> Ungroup.
- A prompt will appear asking you if you want to convert it. Click yes and after Ungroup it one more time.
- You will see that the shape has a transparent
  shape/background. Delete that and group the elements again (if there are more than one).

Done!

Comment: Just a tip, using `<kbd></kbd>` tags makes posts like these a lot clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to export your Illustrator file as EMF or WMF (File > Export). 
They should be compatible with Windows Office software.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/paste from Illustrator into MS Word, then copy/paste from MS Word into PowerPoint. Then you can right-click and "edit picture" to break it apart, recolor, etc. It will be fully scalable. Unfortunately, Powerpoint doesn't support copy/paste directly from Illustrator. (At least 2010 version doesn't.)

Edit: As joojaa has pointed out, you CAN paste directly from Illustartor into Powerpoint, but you have to right-click and paste as a picture. Thanks for the tip, joojaa!

Comment: It does not? Weird at least it works on my pc, you just have to specify your pasting a picture.

Comment: Copy/paste worked for me